# What is the workflow for writing Sass or similar?

Tags: css, sass

I am a developer and I am trying to understand one thing... how does the Sass processor fit into the day to day design/development workflow?

Without it it was something simple like saving the CSS file and refresh the page.

But if you use, let's say, something like SASS, how does it change?

If I got it right:

1. You write your sass files on your favourite text editor
2. Process it in some way
3. Check the results on your localhost (or wherever you have the development version)

Is this how the workflow is with Sass or another CSS pre-processor? And if it is, isn't this time consuming?

Comment: CSS pre-processor are a different way of writing CSS...see - http://sass-lang.com/guide for instance. When they compile they produce normal CSS stylesheets. However, I'm not sure Stack Overflow really the right place for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question. At first SASS can seem to be time consuming but after a little while you truly see the benefits.

You need to work locally (which I recommend anyway) and I use Koala (http://koala-app.com) which processes by SASS file into CSS every time I save. You still link your css in exactly the same way so when you are ready to deploy, you just do it the same where you've always done it.

Answer (score 0):

CSS preprocessors are the demand of the day. They give you the benefit of Variables, Partials and Nesting(VPN as I would call).

The code is written in Less Or Sass and then compiled into .css files using grunt and compass. You can keep a watch to see if the file(s) is/are being changed at any time. Just typing in this command will help

```
sass --watch input.scss:output.css
```

Pre-Processors help in the long run as long code manipulation needs more time and effort and is mistake prone. Definitely, Pre-Processors are better